# Dual axis one linear one logarithmic

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, axis

I'm trying to obtain 2 plots on the same chart, with y dual axis, one with linear scale and the other one with logarithmic scale.
(I know, it's not good practice in general...)
First data range from 0 to 2500, these are the ones I want to see as linear.
Second data range from 0 to 50.000, these ones should be represented with logarithmic scale.
The plot looks ok but I'm not actually sure as I don't manage to handle properly the ticks of the second axis. I would like to see on my second axis an easy logarithmic scale like (100,1000, 10000), how could i do that? I tried to play with the breaks but no success so far.

```
Test<-ggplot()+
      geom_area(
        aes(x=DateReport1,y=TotalCases_log10*1000),
        fill=alpha("grey",0.7),
        data=CountryData)+
      geom_bar(stat="identity",
               aes(x=DateReport1,y=NewCases),
               fill="#D86422",size=0.6,
               data=CountryData)+
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ log10(.)*1000))
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: (1) Rather than `~ log10(.)*1000` have you tried just `log10`? (2) Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. In particular, having access to (at least a subset of) your data would be helpful, or perhaps similar example data that you mock up. You can use the R command `dput()` to output your data in a way that lets others easily copy and paste to set up in their R session. Then you can [edit] your question to include the output of `dput()` so we can run your commands with your data and try to help.

Comment: a secondary y-axis makes for a confusing visualization. Consider using `ggplot2`s [facetting](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html) instead to show multiple variables